# Angularjs: two ng-repeats not showing the correct information in table column

Tags: arrays, angularjs, html-table, row, multiple-columns

I'm trying to create a dynamic table that could hold search results with different amount of columns.

I created a table that should have a row for every entry and a column for every datafield both populated with ng-repeat -functions, but for some reason it doesn't show any information in the columns at all, although it does create correct amount of them.

If I try to show `e` in `{{}}` it shows the correct key that exists. If I try with `i` in `{{}}` it shows the following in each column (the information is same for all columns, but different for every row):

```
{"etunimi":"firstname","sukunimi":"lastname","optunnus":"010101010101011001"}
```

Here is the html:

```
<table id="raporttiTulos" class="resultTable">
        <tr ng-repeat="i in raportointiLista">
                <td ng-repeat=" e in raportointiAvaimet">{{i.e}}</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the function responsible for the incoming data:

```
    $scope.haeMaksut = function(){
            $scope.raportointiAvaimet = {};
            $http.post('/maksuhaku')
             .then(function(res){
                    x = 0;
                    $scope.raportointiLista = res.data.message;
                    for(i in $scope.raportointiLista[0]){
                            $scope.raportointiAvaimet[x] = i;
                    x+=1
                    }
                    console.log($scope.raportointiAvaimet);
                    $scope.maksamattomat = $scope.raportointiLista.length;
                    $scope.lataus = true;
            }, function(error){
                    console.log(error);
            });
    }
```

This is how the key list looks like:

```
Object [ "etunimi", "sukunimi", "optunnus" ]
```

Here are some rows from the data list:

```
[…]
  [0…99]
    0: Object { etunimi: "firstname", sukunimi: "lastname", optunnus: "101010101010101010", … }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of doing that you can directly access object keys.

HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in raportointiLista">
    <td ng-repeat="key in raportointiAvaimet">{{i[key]}}</td>
</tr>
```

Controller

```
$scope.haeMaksut = function () {
    $scope.raportointiAvaimet = {};
    $http.post('/maksuhaku')
        .then(function (res) {
            $scope.raportointiLista = res.data.message;
            $scope.raportointiAvaimet = Object.keys($scope.raportointiLista[0]);
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Comment: Yes I could do that, but if I want to use this same table for another report that contains for example 5 columns with different keys it wouldn't work anymore.

Comment: Good work, it works fine now! Thank you alot! I'd like to ask what is the difference that made it find the right value with your edits?

Comment: You were doing `i.e` which checks for `e` key inside `i` object not the value of `e`.